# Swagger Configuration for controllers from different packages in spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have rest controllers in a spring-boot application.

Project structure:

> Controllers

- Package1

  ControllerClass1.java

  ControllerClass2.java
- Package2

  ControllerClass3.java

  ControllerClass4.java

> Services
>
> Models

**localhost:8080/app/swagger-ui.html shows only one package controllers.**

ControllerClass1

```
     Method1 GET 

     Method2 POST
```

ControllerClass2

```
     Method1 PUT

     Method2 POST
```

I want to put all controllers from all packages on swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed by adding the base package

```
@Bean
public Docket productApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.shivanshu.project"))
            .build();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can configure packages and classes you want instructing Swagger which paths to include

```
.paths(Predicates.or(
                    PathSelectors.ant("/api/v1/pck1/**"),
                    PathSelectors.ant("/api/v1/pck2/**"),
                    PathSelectors.ant("/api/anotherpath/**"))
            )
```

The paths are defined in the Controller (it doesnt matter which package)

```
package com.example.controller;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/pck1")
public class MyController {
```