# Issue with Swagger displaying Controllers in other microservice package

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, openapi, springdoc

I am currently working on an application that utilizes microservices with Spring Boot. Although everything is functioning as expected, I am facing a minor issue with the Controllers.

Specifically, since one of the microservices is using packages from another, I had to utilize the following annotations in the second microservice (package names have been obfuscated):

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"cm.test.p1","cm.test.p2"})`

Now, p2 has its own Controllers package to expose its RESTful APIs. The problem I am facing is that Swagger for p1 is also displaying the Controllers in p2.

I have attempted to exclude the Controller package using the following annotation, but the issue still persists:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"cm.test.p1","cm.test.p2"}
, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="cm.test.p2.*Controller"))
```

and this

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"cm.test.p1","cm.test.p2"},
excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASPECTJ, pattern="cm.test.p2.*Controller+"))
```

Just to mention, I am using springdoc as the maven library.

Any guidance on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger Configuration for controllers from different packages in spring-boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251678/swagger-configuration-for-controllers-from-different-packages-in-spring-boot-app)

Comment: @sidgate Unfortunately no. This would work if I were using springfox as the swagger library. I am using springdoc instead.

Comment: wasn't mentioned in the question. In that case try setting property `springdoc.packagesToScan=cm.test.p1`

Comment: @sidgate you are correct. I have edited my initial question. BTW, this worked! Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @sidgate btw, could you please add this as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to restrict the generated OpenAPI description using package or path configuration using application properties for `springdoc`

```
springdoc.packagesToScan=cm.test.p1
```

More information [here](https://springdoc.org/#selecting-the-rest-controllers-to-include-in-the-documentation)